# Trying to understand the terms given by $\int_0^1 t^m \sin \pi t \: dt$

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

Reading this [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/275E7A1AC29163EEFD7927E606FAB855/S0004972700006742a.pdf/legendre-polynomials-in-irrationality-proofs.pdf) (page $3$, theorem $2$) I got confused.

First is defined the integral $I_n$ as:

\begin{align}
I_n  = (-1)^n \frac{ \pi^{2n} }{(2n)!} \int_0^1 t^{2n}(1-t)^{2n} \sin \pi t \: dt .
\end{align}

Now, $I_n$ consists of terms of the shape:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 t^{m} \sin \pi t \: dt , \: m \leq 2n.
\end{align}

Integrate by parts the integral above:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 t^{m} \sin \pi t \: dt = \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{m(m-1)}{\pi^2}
\int_0^1 t^{m-2} \sin \pi t \: dt.
\end{align}

The following conclusion I don't understand: "Hence $I_n = \pi^{-1}A_n(\pi^{-2}) 
 $, where $A_n$ is an $(n-1)$st degree polynomial with integral coefficients."

I understand the above as being, $I_n = \pi^{-1}( a_{n-1}\pi^{-2(n-1)} + a_{n-2}\pi^{-2(n-2)} + \cdots + a_0).$ But this is wrong.

Can someone give a detailed explanation, please?

Answer (score 0):

I  think that there is typo in the paper; it should be *"Hence* $I_n = \pi^{-1}A_n(\pi^{-2})$ *where* $A_n$ *is an* $\color{red}{n}$ *degree polynomial with integral coefficients."*

I prefered to write it as
$$I_n=\frac 1 \pi \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {a_k} {\pi^{2k}}$$

Using what is given and computing, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \pi I_n \\
 1 & 2-\frac{24}{\pi ^2} \\
 2 & 2-\frac{360}{\pi ^2} +\frac{3360}{\pi ^4}\\
 3 & 2-\frac{1680}{\pi ^2}+\frac{151200}{\pi ^4}-\frac{1330560}{\pi ^6} \\
 4 & 2-\frac{5040}{\pi ^2}+\frac{1663200}{\pi
   ^4}-\frac{121080960}{\pi ^6}+\frac{1037836800}{\pi ^8}\\
 5 & 2-\frac{11880}{\pi ^2}+\frac{10090080}{\pi ^4}-\frac{2421619200}{\pi ^6}+\frac{158789030400}{\pi
   ^8}-\frac{1340885145600}{\pi ^{10}} \\
 6 &2 -\frac{24024}{\pi ^2}+\frac{43243200}{\pi ^4}-\frac{24700515840}{\pi^6}+\frac{5028319296000}{\pi ^8}-\frac{309744468633600}{\pi
   ^{10}}+\frac{2590590101299200}{\pi ^{12}}
\end{array}
\right)$$

In fact, given by a CAS, there is a general expression in terms of hypergeometric function
$$I_n=(-1)^n\frac{  \pi ^{2 n+\frac{3}{2}} }{2^{4 n+2}\,\Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\,
   _2F_3\left(n+1,n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2},2 n+\frac{3}{2},2 n+2;-\frac{\pi
   ^2}{4}\right)$$

Comment: My question was more about how seeing the integral after integrating by parts helps you conclude that $I_n=\frac 1 \pi \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {a_k} {\pi^{2k}}$. Thanks for answering though.